# Pandas using group by on one column, then max on the other get non duplicated values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like below

```
link_id     uploaded_timestamp       file_path
ScUwGwuS1k  2020-07-21 00:00:00 UTC  /home/user/Docs/file.pdf
ScUwGwuS1k  2020-12-16 00:00:00 UTC  /home/user/Downloads/file.pdf
```

In the given data set I have multiple cases where link_id's are the same, but timestamps and file_paths for them differ. My input dataset has about 13k+ rows.

I would like to now distinct only one row for each of the link_ids based on the latest uploaded_timestemp.

What I already came up with is as follows:

```
new_df = pd.read_csv('input/input_csf_file.csv')

idx = new_df.groupby(['link_id'])
idx = idx.max()
```

However, when I checked randomly some id's, it looks like, the values for uploaded_timestamp was taken the latest, but file_path was not relevant, like below:

```
link_id     uploaded_timestamp       file_path
ScUwGwuS1k  2020-12-16 00:00:00 UTC  /home/user/Docs/file.pdf
```

Could you please help me with that?

Comment: Use `df = new_df.loc[new_df.groupby('link_id')['uploaded_timestamp'].idxmax()]`

Comment: Your solution gives me a ValueError exception

Comment: Is converted `uploaded_timestamp` to datetimes ?

Comment: I haven't done it previously. After conversion, it works perfectly! Thank you very much!